# Error in creating own package while doing exactly what instruction says

Tags: r

I have a problem with creating my own package in R. I deem that it's very strange because I'm doing exactly when the instruction says.

I've done what was in the instruction :

1. Create functions I want in my package
2. Open new project -> R package
3. Create description and put them info 'man' folder
4. Press Ctr+Shift+B

I have problem, because I get this massage :

'UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

Warning: invalid package 'mynewpackage'

Error: ERROR: no packages specified'

I tried to find the solution in internet. It seem's that this is often problem, but I couldn't find the answer in this specific problem. Do you have any idea's how can I fix it ?

Comment: UNC paths are a bane. You need to open R (or Rstudio) so that it is working from C:\ (or some other local drive) not something like //myremote_drive/

Comment: Okey I see. But let's assume that I'm stubborn person, is there any possibility to create package using UNC paths ?

Comment: perhaps, but there are enough hurdles to making an R package without adding more